# Jsoup selector notation for CLASSLESS **and** IDLESS elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors, jsoup

This CSS selector picks up  elements without a class attribute:

```
a:not([class])
```

This CSS selector picks up  elements without an id attribute:

```
a:not([id])
```

But what is the syntax for a CSS selector picks up  elements that have no id ***and*** no class?

I tried the following:

```
a:not([class][id])
```

But what it did is pick up  elements that have no id *or* have no class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
a:not([class]):not([id])
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f27zc/)